# (Django Allauth) 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm trying to implement a CustomUser model in Django Allauth. When I used the allauth provided login template, I encountered this error

[image]

My Customer User Model in

**users/models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Password should not be none')
        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        if user.is_superuser is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if user.is_staff is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')
        user.save()
        return user
    
    
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users should have a Email')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    

AUTH_PROVIDERS = {'facebook': 'facebook', 'google': 'google',
                  'twitter': 'twitter', 'email': 'email'}
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    about = models.TextField(_(
        'about'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    auth_provider = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=False,
        null=False, default=AUTH_PROVIDERS.get('email'))
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**settings.py**

```py
""" custom user """
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

""" allauth """
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    
]

SITE_ID = 1

# Provider specific settings
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    
}

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False    # This removes the username field
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
```

After searching about the above error, I tried the following:

1. Make sure AUTH_USER_MODEL is set in **settings.py**

```py
""" custom user """
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

2. Changing AbtractBaseUser to AbstractUser in **models.py**

This leads to another error:
[image]

3. Add username field in CustomUser:
   Another issue popped up which I tried to fix but in the end had to delete the migrations folder and redo.
   [image]
4. Check logged_in.txt and trace the user variable:
   I found that `user = get_user_model()`, which is defined as follows:

```py
def get_user_model():
    """
    Return the User model that is active in this project.
    """
    try:
        return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
    except ValueError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL must be of the form 'app_label.model_name'")
    except LookupError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
        )
```

It's strange since I have already defined `AUTH_USER_MODEL = users.CustomUser` above.

I'm quite lost at this point. Could you show me a way to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I also sweated on this, but I found the following in the documentation which resolved my issue:

> **Custom User Models**
>
> If you use a custom user model you need to specify what field
> represents the username, if any. Here, username really refers to the
> field representing the nickname that the user uses to login, and not
> to some unique identifier (possibly including an e-mail address) as is
> the case for Django’s **AbstractBaseUser.USERNAME_FIELD.**
>
> Therefore, if your custom user model does not have a username field
> (again, not to be mistaken with an e-mail address or user id), you
> will need to set **ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD** to **None**.
> This will disable username related functionality in allauth. Remember
> to also set **ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED** to **False**.

https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-user-models

Comment: It works: ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD to None. Sometimes we set just ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False, but is could be not enough.